# Apache Parquet Writer throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when writing Avro

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet, avro

I am trying to generate some parquet files from my POJO classes. I am mostly successful in that but AvroWriter is giving me a failure when I try to save a list of custom POJO object.

```
 try {
     ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer = writerMap.computeIfAbsent(separator, pWriter -> {
         try {
             return AvroParquetWriter
                    .<GenericRecord>builder(path)
                    .withSchema(schema)
                    .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
                    .withConf(config)
                    .withValidation(false)
                    .withPageWriteChecksumEnabled(false)
                    .withDictionaryEncoding(false)
                    .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                    .build();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Error creating Parquet writer", e);
         }
     });

     writer.write(convertToGenericRecord(item, schema));
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     log.error("Exception while writing to parquet file", ex);
 }
```

This is my Schema:

```
 public static Schema getServiceOrdersJsonSchema2() {
     Schema arraySchema = SchemaBuilder.array()
               .items(SchemaBuilder.record("ServiceOrderJson")
               .namespace("ServiceOrders")
               .fields()
                   .name("value1").type().stringType().noDefault()
                   .name("value2").type().stringType().noDefault()
                   .name("value3").type().longType().noDefault()
                   .name("value4").type().stringType().noDefault()
                   .name("value5").type().booleanType().noDefault()
               .endRecord());
    return arraySchema;
}
```

This is my POJO class:

```
public class ServiceOrderJson {
    public String value1;
    public String value2;
    public long value3;
    public String value4;
    public Boolean value5;
}
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$MessageColumnIORecordConsumer.addBinary(MessageColumnIO.java:476) ~[parquet-column-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValueWithoutConversion(AvroWriteSupport.java:362) ~[parquet-avro-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValue(AvroWriteSupport.java:291) ~[parquet-avro-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeRecordFields(AvroWriteSupport.java:204) ~[parquet-avro-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.write(AvroWriteSupport.java:178) ~[parquet-avro-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:138) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:310) ~[parquet-hadoop-1.13.1.jar:1.13.1]
    at com.mbti.cddm.analyticsintegration.writer.ParquetItemWriter.generateParquetFiles(ParquetItemWriter.java:123) ~[classes/:na]
```

I was expecting that Array is going to be recognized and written into a file.